# Copy range of cells from current worksheet to a text file while deleting previous text file

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA code below was modified with the help of user taller.

The code:

1. Copies a range of cells from my current worksheet
2. Creates a text file with name "Unsuppression_*dd.MM*_01", where dd.MM is the current date and month, and 01 is the version number 1.
3. Pastes the cell value to the text file and closes it.
4. When the code is run for a second time, it copies the cell values and then creates a text file with incremented version ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_02") and pastes to that.
   It also deletes the previous version text file ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_01")
5. When the code is run for a third time, it copies the cell values and then creates a text file with incremented version ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_03") and pastes to that.
   It also deletes the previous version text file ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_02").

Example:
Suppose I execute the code five times today, the last txt file created is "Unsuppression_20.11_05" which is the only text file present in my folder Path.

```vb
Sub StackOverfolow_UpdatetextfilewithVersion()
    ' Define folder path
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Users\kuldeep\Desktop\SIM_macro\New exp\Unsuppression_" & Format(Date, "dd.MM") & "_"
    
    ' Define range to copy
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H8")
    
    ' Copy values to array
    Dim valuesArray As Variant
    valuesArray = copyRange.Value
    
    Dim versionNumber As Integer, aTxt
    Dim fName As String, baseFolder As String
    baseFolder = "C:\Users\kbkmth\Desktop\SIM_macro\New exp\"
    versionNumber = 1
    
    ' Check for existing versions and delete them
    fName = Dir(folderPath & "*.txt")
    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        ' Delete the previous version with a delay
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' 1 second delay
        Kill baseFolder & fName
        aTxt = Split(fName, "_")
        ' Increment version number
        versionNumber = CInt(Left(aTxt(UBound(aTxt)), 2)) + 1
    End If
    
    ' Open file for writing with the correct version number
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open folderPath & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".txt" For Output As fileNumber
    
    ' Write values to file
    For i = 1 To UBound(valuesArray, 1)
        Print #fileNumber, valuesArray(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    ' Close file
    Close fileNumber
End Sub
```

I'm facing one issue.
When I run the code after changing my date in my Windows system settings, the code creates version "01" with the new date and retains the last created version from the prior day.

Is it possible to delete the prior day's text file?

Example of the issue:
Suppose I execute the code five times today, the last text file created is "Unsuppression_20.11_05" which is the only text file present in my folder Path.
When I run the code after changing the date to November 21st (in my Windows system settings), a new text document named "Unsuppression_21.11_01" is created.

My folder Path still has the text file "Unsuppression_20.11_05" (last created version from the previous day).

Comment: Does the date have to be `dd.mm`. Is is possible to change and add year ?

Comment: Yes, i need the date in the format dd.MM, because i have to upload the text file to a SharePoint every time a new version is created, and the SME of my team insists that the text file name to be in the format "Unsuppression_dd.MM_00" only. It helps them in their other tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern match the `Unsuppression_dd.MM_00` with a Regular Expression to extract the `dd.MM` and compare with current date. Increment version for those with current date only and fill a collection with file names to delete later. I have put the code in a function to keep your existing code cleaner.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Const basefolder = "C:\Users\kbkmth\Desktop\SIM_macro\New exp\"
    
    ' determine filename
    Dim fnew As String
    fnew = getNextVersion(basefolder, "Unsuppression_")
    If fnew = "" Then
         MsgBox "Error in getNextVersion()"
         Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' create file
    Dim fileNumber As Integer
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open basefolder & fnew For Output As fileNumber
    ' write text
    Close fileNumber
    
End Sub

Function getNextVersion(basefolder, fname) As String

    Dim regex As Object, m As Object, sm As Object
    Dim dt As Date, today As Date, yr As Long
    Dim f As String, fnew As String, verno As Long
    Dim colDelete As Collection
    Set colDelete = New Collection
    
    ' pattern match filenames _mm.dd_nn.txt
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
       .Global = False
       .MultiLine = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = fname & "(\d\d)\.(\d\d)_(\d\d).txt" ' pattern
    End With
    
    ' initial version
    verno = 1
    
    ' current date
    today = Date
    yr = Year(today)
    
    ' scan folder for files
    f = Dir(basefolder & "*.txt")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        ' match filenam
        Set m = regex.Execute(f)
        If m.Count = 1 Then
            ' extract dd and mm
            Set sm = m(0).submatches
            dt = DateSerial(yr, sm(1), sm(0))
            'is date today
            If dt = today Then
                ' check if a version number exists
                If sm(2) >= verno Then verno = sm(2) + 1
            End If
            
            ' add to collection to delete later
            colDelete.Add f
            'Debug.Print verno, sm(0), sm(1), sm(2)
        End If
        f = Dir ' next file
    Loop
    
    ' build new filename
    fnew = fname & Format(today, "dd.mm") & Format(verno, "_00") & ".txt"
    
    ' delete old file(s)
    Dim msg As String, n As Long
    For n = 1 To colDelete.Count
        Kill basefolder & colDelete(n)
        msg = msg & vbLf & colDelete(n)
    Next
    MsgBox "New file" & vbLf & fnew & vbLf & "Files deleted" & msg

    getNextVersion = fnew

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @CDP1802. The code that you provided functions flawlessly and produces the exact required output for me. Also, the final message box, which displays both the newly generated and removed file names - is wonderful! That helps a lot with missing on file names and even confirming that the right file is uploaded. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you could delete the old versioned files before writing the new one:

```
... (code)

Kill "C:\Users\kuldeep\Desktop\SIM_macro\New exp\Unsuppression*.*"  '<= new added line

' Open file for writing with the correct version number
Dim fileNumber As Integer
... (code)
```

I'd suggest making backup copies of the folder before testing it

Comment: Hi @user3598756, thank you for your response. I added the code line you suggested to my vba code, and it worked perfectly the first time ,i.e, it deleted the previous day's last version text file and created the current day's text file with version 01. However, when the code is run for the second time, the vba code line you indicated in your response causes me to receive an error (Run time error 53: File not Found) . I believe this is the case because my folder path no longer contains any text file versions from the prior day. Can you please help me get around this?